# Audio Recording and Out of memory Exception

Tags: android, out-of-memory

hi
 i have audio recording in my i use mediarecorder class for recding audio but i have out of memory exception when i reach 2 m , that my limit. i given my code below.

time

private static void audiorecding()
    {
        if (audio_recding_stop_flag == 0) {
            audio_recding_stop_flag = 1;

```
        recorder.stop();
        recorder.reset();
        recorder.release();
        recorder=new MediaRecorder();
        int maxtime = audio_seekbar_play_indication.getMax();
        audio_seekbar_progress = 0;
        audio_seekbar_incr = maxtime/ AngiesData.gettotalaudiorecdingtimeinseconds(audio_recding_time.getText().toString());
        audio_recding_time.stop();
        recd_stop_audio.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.rec_btn);
        audio_play_pause.setEnabled(true);
        delete_recding.setEnabled(true);

       AngiesData.angiesListContext.setAudioRecd(true);
       AngiesData.angiesListContext.setAudioRecdingTime((String) audio_recding_time.getText());
    } 
    else {


        audio_recding_stop_flag = 0;


        try {

            audio_play_pause.setEnabled(false);
            delete_recding.setEnabled(false);
            recd_stop_audio.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.recording_stop);
            audio_recding_time .setBase(SystemClock.elapsedRealtime());
            audio_recding_time.start(); 
            recorder = new MediaRecorder();
            recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC); // AudioSource
            recorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.DEFAULT); // OutputFormat
            recorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.DEFAULT);
            path = InitialValueLoader.sanitizePath("Audio/VoiceReport");
            InitialValueLoader.filecheck(path);
            recorder.setOutputFile(path);
            recorder.setMaxDuration(120000);
            recorder.prepare();
            recorder.start();


        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }   
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest useing a Chronometer instead of a timer

Comment: i also use the chrometer but problem still there

Comment: i have solved my problem by working audio recding as separte activity

Comment: can you please post code of audio recording with chronometer please?

Answer (score 2):

I would try something with the AudioRecord-Class ( http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioRecord.html), use the read()-function with a while-loop and keep going until you got your 2 min. of samples (check the sampleRate, e.g. 44.1 Khz => 44100 smpls/sec => 60*44100 smpl/min). Making sure you have 2 min. of audio with the help of a timer is not a good idea. With timers you can never be sure on the precision, if another thread is interferring your timer will be evoked later, and in audio samples speaking it might be MUCH later.

Comment: i have recorded audio with this class the problem is resulting file not supported by my device (motorolla droid)

Answer (score 0):

In programming if you have to deal with timings generally all time values are in milliseconds. You are trying to stop the recording after two seconds there not two minutes which would be `120000` milliseconds.

Comment: @Sudeep SR it wasn't meant to be the solution but a general hint.